# Trying to understand how to conduct a power analysis of logistic regressions

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-power

I am have conducted some logistic regressions in R comparing an estimate of ancestry with some other variables. My advisor has asked me to do power analyses on these. I do not have the greatest background in statistics, and I need some help.

Each regression is fairly simple, it is just a logistic regression testing association with one variable in a subset of my data.

I have come across some calculators such as this
https://rdrr.io/cran/WebPower/man/wp.logistic.html or https://webpower.psychstat.org/models/reg02/
and this
[https://www.dartmouth.edu/~eugened/power-samplesize.php](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Eeugened/power-samplesize.php)

but I am very lost. How exactly do I calculate p0 and p1 or a minimum detectable odds ratio?

My ancestry values make up my x-axis (and range from 0 to 1), but none of my ancestry data points are 0 or 1. Are p0 and p1 based on the regression equation calculated by R, or my actual data?

I cannot seem to find a good tutorial for how to conduct these power analyses, so I am coming here for help.

CLARIFICATION
My x-axis variable is a float measure of ancestry ranging from 0 and 1. I am testing whether various binary variables (absence or presence of traits, 0 or 1) are associated with ancestry. Our sample sizes are small, so we want to do a power analysis to determine how likely we could actually detect a true positive.

Comment: Can you add more detail around your data and what your research question is?

Comment: @DemetriPananos, see update

Comment: So is your outcome a float from 0 to 1?  You call it your "x axis" variable but also say you want to measure the association between other binary variables and ancestry

Comment: @DemetriPananos, I have a measure of ancestry for each individual in my dataset. This measure is a float between 0 and 1 (though none of the individuals I am testing are exactly 0 or exactly 1). I testing association between ancestry and presence/absence variables (e.g., did this individual have trait A or not).

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this should be fairly straight forward.  Since the outcome (has trait, does not have trait) is a binary variable, you can use logistic regression with the ancestry variable as a predictor.

Because you have a fixed sample size, a better approach is to calculate power but rather to calculate what effects can be reasonable estimated with a specific statistical power.  The formula for this is

$$ \pm \beta_{j}^{a}=\frac{z_{1-\alpha / 2}+z_{\gamma}}{\sigma_{x_{j}} \sqrt{n p(1-p)\left(1-\rho_{j}^{2}\right)}}$$

Here:

- $\beta$ is the log odds ratio for the ancestry variable
- $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $1-\alpha/2$ quantile of a standard normal.  If you use a standard false positive rate of $\alpha=0.05$ then $z_{1-\alpha/2} = 1.96$
- $z_\gamma$ is the $\gamma$ quantile of a standard normal, where $\gamma$ is the desired statistical power.  If you use a standard power of $\gamma=0.8$ then $z_\gamma = 0.84$.
- $\sigma_{x}$ is the standard deviation of the ancestry predictor.
- $n$ is the sample size
- $p$ is the marginal probability of the outcome (the sample mean of the outcome ignoring the ancestry variable).
- $1-\rho^2$ is the variance inflation factor, but since you only have a single predictor you can ignore this.

This formula will tell you the log odds ratio you can detect at a given power with your sample.

Comment: The ancestry predictor doesn't have a standard deviation in this case, however.

Comment: @dnv89 and why would that be

Comment: I think I confused myself. You mean the standard deviation from R from the `glm(formula = variable ~ ancestry, family = binomial, data = dataset)` not from the ancestry data itself, correct?

Comment: @dnv89 No, I mean the output of `sd(ancestry)`

Comment: Standard deviation of the ancestry sampleset going into the logistic, OK, I can do that

Comment: what is the range that beta should take. Depending on the test, it ranges from ~4.5 to ~22. My numerator is 2.8 for all tests (1.96+0.84).

Comment: @dnv It should be a single number, there should not be a range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132993/discussion-between-dnv89-and-demetri-pananos).

Comment: @Demtri - just to double check, is the numerator supposed to be the two Z summed or multiplied?

Comment: @dnv89 its a sum.